# How can I send/export the whole content of a variable to a text file/xml file/clipboard?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I want to send the content of an instance, in tree-form preferrably, to somebody. A print screen will not do because the class is too complex.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to turn the output back into an instance? In that case, the other answers are spot on.

If you just want to manually inspect the contents of the instance, ideally your classes would all implement `toString()` and you could redirect this to a file.

If you haven't got good toStrings, you can use the following (e.g. in Eclipse's Expressions view)

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(
    new java.io.File("C:\\objectAsString.txt"),
    org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(
    variableToInspect,
    org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE))
```

if you have commons-lang3 and commons-io on the classpath.

Comment: too bad i can't use your code in expressions view ( i get a "could not resolve type org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.toStringBuilder" error)  even tho i added the jar to  the project build path

Comment: Oh, and i'm guessing the reason that FileUtils works is because it is already part of the libs included in the target platform i'm using.

Answer (score 1):

you could use Xml parsing or serialization as vidhya just said.

Xml more reflexive, it is easier to use or read in any type of program, you won't have versioning problems and many many other good features.

Serializing can be easier if you use this exact application on the other end. but many bugs can find their way into your application.

for xml parsing you can use java XML library or many third party libraries like Dom4j.
Xml parsing is easy enough, You can add a toXml and fromXml to each one of your entities, and define how you would like that entity being parsed.