# Unable to use org.apache.common.lang3.builder.toStringBuilder in eclipse's expressions view, during debug

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, view

This was my original problem : [How can I send/export the whole content of a variable to a text file/xml file/clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629544/how-can-i-send-export-the-whole-content-of-a-variable-to-a-text-file-xml-file-cl) (the question is still open to suggestions BTW) . Now i am trying to execute the code given by artbristol inside the Expressions View but haven't been succesful, even though i did add the jars to my build path.Apparently including the lang3 jar in the build path does not make it visible to eclipse when debugging (I can, however, import lang3 classes into my project's .java files after adding the jar to the build path )

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding whole content

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(
    new java.io.File("C:\\objectAsString.txt"),
    org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(
    variableToInspect,
    org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE))
```

to expression view, yes it won't show you the content.

You have to add only this:

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(
        variableToInspect,
        org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE)
```

Then select the expression in ExpressionView, it will show you the content.

Comment: i copied your code, replaced variableToInspect with my variable and it give the same error: could not resolve type: org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder

Comment: I just did it again, I have commons-io-2.0.1.jar and commons-lang3-3.1.jar in my build path, and I can see it in expression view

Comment: also try cleaning and rebuilding your project

Comment: I created a new java project from scratch and it seems to work...i don't get it, why does it not work with my original plugin?.. i did clean and rebuild the proj and i also reloaded the target platform :|